# How can I return the nearest value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

If I had a table something like

```
ID     VALUE
1      1000
2      1500
3      2000
```

and I were to select `value='1999'` it would return the 3rd row. If I were to select `1200` instead, it would return the 1st row. How do I do that in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a nice question :)

```
SELECT VALUE FROM mytable ORDER BY ABS(VALUE-1999) LIMIT 1
```

Of course that 1999 will be a variable in real.

**[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92b88/2)**

Comment: Hanky is using the `ABS` function to find the closest neighbor to the value 1999.  Wicked answer...you get an upvote!

Comment: select salary from Employee order by ABS(max(salary)) limit 1; by running this query gives me an error like: Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, value, ABS(1999 - value) as delta
from YOUR_TABLE
order by delta
LIMIT 1
```

That will calculate the delta between your request and all data in the table and will order by the smallest delta.. so if you limit the request to 1, you will have the nearest row !

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, value, ABS(1999 - value) as number
from tablename
order by number
limit 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I didnt try it But i think it should work

```
$query="SELECT abs(value-'".$_REQUEST['myValue']."') as num,value from table order by num asc limit 1";
```